# Does RSA operate over a Finite Field (Galois Field)?

Tags: rsa, finite-field

Is it correct to say that RSA operates over a Finite Field (Galois Field)? In this case GF(p)?
I do understant that the modulo in RSA is not itself a prime number, but all the operations (multiplication, inversion) occur as if it is a GF(p).

Comment: Nope, RSA is defined over an residue class ring.

Comment: @DrLecter: Technically, your comment does not contradict the statement in question: a residue class ring *may* be (isomorphic to) a finite field. You want to append "that is not a field".

Comment: @yyyyyy jup, thats correct! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, RSA encryption and signature is performed in (the multiplicative semigroup of) the factor ring $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ which is *not* a field since the non-zero elements $kp+n\mathbb Z$ (for $0<k<q$) and $kq+n\mathbb Z$ (for $0<k<p$) do not have multiplicative inverses. (However, one easily observes that all other non-zero elements *are* invertible, as their representants are coprime to $n=pq$).

Comment: While the correct answer to the question is "no", the RSA definitions also can work for those elements, which are not coprime to $n$. Since they are zero divisors, they dont have inverse elements, but it can still be true that $x^{ed} = x$, with $x$ not coprime to $n$. I cant recall the exact requirement there, but there are topics on this on crypto-SE.

Comment: @tylo $x^{ed} = x$ holds for all $x$ in RSA.

Answer (score -3):

William Stalling says

> RSA is based on exponentiation in a finite (Galois) field over integers modulo a prime

Source: http://williamstallings.com/Extras/Security-Notes/lectures/publickey.html

Comment: The RSA modulus is not prime, so arithmetic modulo n is no finite field. So that statement is either wrong, or at least very misleading. (Using a sufficiently loose interpretation of "based on" you could say that private key arithmetic using the Chinese-Remainder-Theorem works in several finite fields, one per factor of the modulus, but I don't think that's a useful interpretation)